# Name for a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, terminology, quadratic-forms

Given a matrix $B\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ what do we call vectors $v$ such that for $$v'Bv=0$$ holds?

Is there a name for these?

Comment: You might call $v'$ _"orthogonal"_ to $v$ with respect to the bilinear form induced by $B$. That's what I would call it, however some people might associate _"orthogonal"_ with scalar products which might be an issue if your $B$ is weaker.

Comment: The $w$ with $w'Bw = 0$ are collectively called the null cone.

Comment: ahhhh @WillJagy so it is a convex set?

Comment: @Robut no. In 3-space, the set with $x^2 + y^2 - z^2$ is the standard doubled cone.

Comment: ahh :( too bad....

Comment: An accurate term is "isotropic vectors" (https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Isotropic_vector)

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting $B$ as a bilinear  form, these are called [null vectors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_vector).  (The zero vector is usually excluded.)
As Will Jagy mentions, the entire set is called the null cone for the form.

Comment: is it also convex.. cone sounds convex but you never know in this math business unless proven.

Comment: @Robut it’s just the surface of the cone, so you can easily see that it’s not convex in 3 space for $B=I_3$